# Convergence of a sequence in $\mathbb R^n$ with a special property

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

***Hi folks, I'm trying to prove (or find a counterexample) of this statement:***

Let $(x_k)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R^n$
 such that  $(x_k - x_{k+1})\to0$,

show that $(x_k)$ converge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac1{k}$.

Also,
I think you should use
different letters
for the dimension
($\mathbb R^n$)
and index
($x_n - x_{n+1}$).

Comment: that's true. thanks for the tips!